# How much weight can a 2x4 wall support?

Tags: walls, load-bearing, load

I would like to build a desk and attach it to my wall like so:

[image: poorly drawn desk and wall]

I have a countertop surface that's about 6' long by 2' deep. It's pretty heavy. I would like to support it by mounting a 2x4 horizontally across the wall, and rest/mount the back edge of the countertop to that 2x4. I would also make some triangular supports, possibly out of 2x4's or plywood, and at the bottom of those supports have a second 2x4 mounted to the wall like the one at the top. Structurally, I'm sure the countertop and supports will be strong enough.

What I am concerned about is the amount of weight pulling out on the wall. We're going to have our kids at this desk for school, so they'll probably be leaning on it, sitting on it, and otherwise abusing the desk as you do as a kid.

How much weight can a standard wall support before it yanks the studs or starts bowing the wall out? 500lbs? 1000? I'm assuming that the further away from the wall this desk reaches the more twisting force it's going to put on the wall, but I'm not entirely sure.

I can't butt the desk up against the wall to the left, and there's no wall on the right.
Will a regular 2x4 wall support this kind of weight, or do I need some type of foot for it?

Comment: If you plan to attach this to the wall with regular screws then the repeated abuse will eventually rip the screws out of the stud well before the studs fails. If you use lag bolts then it will feel quite sturdy for years to come. To achieve best results then get bolts through the 2x4 and washers. Is there a specific opposition to to having legs touch the floor?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus lag screws. Everything that I plan on adding will provide plenty of support - the only failure point I'm worried about is the wall itself. My wife hates hitting her knees on table legs, so wants to avoid having them.

Comment: The static load of the counter should not be a problem for the lag bolts especially since your drawing indicates at least 4 support braces beneath. The weight of children leaning on it should also be zero issue but try to keep their butts off of it and certainly no jumping on it. My suggestion is to just build it as planned and test it yourself with your own weight. If you find that over time things are starting to go south then inconvenience your wife and add legs.

Comment: If this wall is not a load bearing wall then it could be flimsily attached where it meets the ceiling so this would be the main point of concern for failure and not so much bowing the wall.

Comment: Fwiw products like this exist https://www.amazon.com/Yes4All-Heavy-Mounted-Crossfit-Training/dp/B019H3C8L4 and I would imagine the strain you envision is quite possibly similar to a 150-250 pound person applying dynamic and swinging pressure.

Answer (score 1):

[From this LINK](https://findanyanswer.com/how-strong-is-2x4#:%7E:text=If%20there%20is%20no%20strong,material%20up%20to%20its%20limit.)

The 2x4 wall can handle around 1000 pounds vertically. But you put the limit to the test meaning you are probably breaking the wall before reaching 1000 pounds.

Use a joint or two, a stud wall helps, or doubling the layer could help, anything to reinforce the wall if the main concerns are the wall breaking out because abused by children.

And this question can be found in the discussion here :
[DIYchatroom.com](https://www.diychatroom.com/threads/2-x-4-strength.78507/)